# Issue on migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I recently migrated my app from .NET Core 2.2  to .NET 6 and upgraded the C# language from C#8 to C#10.

The app uses SQL Server and it's based on database first.

After migration, I noticed 2 changes:

1. Entity Framework database first changes column mapping (column's names), Example:

   - The column name in the database: "Topic_Id",
   - The column name in the entity will change to: "TopicId" (Removing "_"):

   Is there a way that I have the exact column name in both the SQL server and Entity Framework?

   Please note I am generating the Entity using Scaffold-DbContext:

   > PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(servername);Database=(dbname);MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=usr;Password=pass" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data/DB -force
2. After moving to the .NET 6, I need to rewrite my queries - I need to convert them to IEnumerable.

   Is there a way that I avoid rewriting all queries?

   - In .NET Core 2.2:

     ```
     db.TblUserCredential UserCredential = this.DbContext.TblUserCredential
        .Where(x => x.CredentialTypeNavigation.Code.ToLower().Contains("kingsid"))
        .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Identifier.Equals(identifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     ```
   - In .NET 6:

     ```
     db.TblUserCredential? UserCredential = ((IEnumerable<db.TblUserCredential>)this.DbContext.TblUserCredentials.Include(x => x.CredentialTypeNavigation))
       .Where(x => x.CredentialTypeNavigation.Code != null && x.CredentialTypeNavigation.Code.ToLower().Contains("kingsid"))
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Identifier != null && x.Identifier.Equals(identifier, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     ```

am I missing anything? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For the first part (Entity Framework database first changes column mapping) I solve the problem by adding "-UseDatabaseNames" to the command:
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servername;Database=Databasename;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=usr;Password=pass" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data/DB  -UseDatabaseNames -force

but I'm still struggling with the second part of my question (re-writing all queries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Example: The column name in the database: "Topic_Id", The column name in the entity will change to: "TopicId" (Removing "_"):

Try specifying `-UseDatabaseNames` (or `--use-database-names` for .NET CLI) in the scaffold command - check out [Preserving database names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#preserving-database-names) section of the `scaffold` docs.

> Is there a way that I avoid rewriting all queries?

No. EF Core in 2nd  version had a nasty little feature which was enabled by default - automatic client side evaluation for queries which it could not translate (i.e. it would silently fetch potentially excessive data and perform the rest of operations at the client-side). The following [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) in EF Core 3 removed this feature and the only option to trigger client side evaluation is to convert query to `IEnumerable` (for example using `AsENumerable`). I highly recommend you to investigate the queries and rewrite them in a way so the can be translated completely.